# Generate a movie file using AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video

Is it possible to create a program using AS3 that would allow the user to download a copy of a dynamic, self generated video into an AVI, MOV or MP4 format???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash's standard video format is FLV/F4V, and there are a few libraries and classes out there that help you create your own on the fly during runtime.

If you are running on AIR, you can use: http://www.zeropointnine.com/blog/simpleflvwriteras-as3-class-to-create-flvs/ to generate uncompressed FLVs

Comment: Can you reffer me to any of these libraries you mentioned? thanks

Comment: @EddyXP The library I linked to is the only one I can remember at this time. I am pretty sure I have seen others, but I couldn't find anything in my bookmarks, in with a quick google sorry.